# Traversing tree with recursion works strange (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree

I've started to dig into the Tree's theme. And I've found strange (for me) behaviour.

```
class tree_node {
  constructor(n_array) {
    this.n_array = n_array;
    this.descendants = [];
    this.child();
  }
  child() {
    if (this.n_array.length !=1){
      let m = Math.floor(this.n_array.length / 2);
      let l = this.n_array.slice(0,m);
      let r = this.n_array.slice(m);
      const left = new tree_node(l);
      const right = new tree_node(r);
      this.descendants.push(left, right);
    }
    else return 0
  }
}
```

So, here I've created a node structure, which gets an integer array, and splits it in half till leaves will not contain only one element of the array.

```
let n_array = [1,3,2,5];
root_node = new tree_node(n_array);
```

Now I want to walk through the tree and alert the "n_array" of every node.
I've supposed that it should be like this

```
function show_tree(root_node){
  if (root_node.descendants.lenght != 0){
    root_node.descendants.forEach(element => {
      return show_tree(element);
    });
  }
  else {
    alert(root_node.n_array)
    return 0;
  } 
}
```

But it doesn't work. If I use a web browser console then ***root.descendants.length*** gives me the length. But in my recursion, it doesn't. Every time it's ***undefined***

I've cut more and more from the code and finally, I've got this.

```
function show_tree(root_node){
  alert(root_node.n_array)
  root_node.descendants.forEach(element => {
    return show_tree(element);
  });  
}
```

The working solution works, but I don't understand why.
I expect that it will run into an error, because at the end of the tree ***root_node.descendants*** will be ***undefined***.

And what's even worse - I don't understand why this recursion stops and does not go into an endless loop if in every call ***root_node.descendants  !=0*** ...
Please help me to understand

1. Why my first version of ***show_tree*** doesn't work
2. Why the last one is working.

Comment: You mistyped `.length` (check spelling!!!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have effectively built a tree structure that looks something like so:

```
    [1, 3, 2, 5]
      /       \
  [1, 3]     [2, 5]
   /   \      /   \
  [1]  [3]   [2]   [5] 
   |    |     |     |
  [ ]  [ ]   [ ]   [ ]
```

In your first function, you have a few issues. The immediate issue is that you are using `.lenght` and not `.length`. The next thing to notice about your function is when it is performing its `alert()`s. In your case, you're only performing an `alert()` when a node has an empty array as its `descendants` property. In the above tree diagram, you'll notice that's only the case for your last nodes `[1]`, `[3]`, `[2]`, and `[5]`, so these are alerted. All other nodes that you traverse do have non-empty descendants, so those are not alerted/logged to the screen:

```js
class tree_node {
  constructor(n_array) {
    this.n_array = n_array;
    this.descendants = [];
    this.child();
  }
  child() {
    if (this.n_array.length !=1){
      let m = Math.floor(this.n_array.length / 2);
      let l = this.n_array.slice(0,m);
      let r = this.n_array.slice(m);
      const left = new tree_node(l);
      const right = new tree_node(r);
      this.descendants.push(left, right);
    }
  }
}

let n_array = [1,3,2,5];
root_node = new tree_node(n_array); 

function show_tree(root_node){
  if (root_node.descendants.length != 0){
    root_node.descendants.forEach(element => {
      show_tree(element);
    });
  }
  else {
    console.log(root_node.n_array); // replaced with console.log (as this is a more preferred way of logging data)
  } 
}

show_tree(root_node);
// Logs:
// [1]
// [3]
// [2]
// [5]
```

Unlike your first function, your second function alerts every node it visits, not just those without descendants. That's because your `alert()` is the first line of the function, so it will always run the alert for every node that the `show_tree()` function is called with.

> I expect that it will run into an error, because at the end of the
> tree root_node.descendants will be undefined

If you look at your `tree_node` class, you'll notice that every node that you create gets a `descendants` property that gets assigned to an empty array within your constructor. As a result, when you traverse/loop over your tree and make further recursive calls, each node you pass into your `show_tree()` function will have a `descendants` property - just sometimes the `descendants` of a node will be an empty array. As a result, no error occurs when you use:

```js
root_node.descendants.forEach(..)
```

as it is valid to call `.forEach()` on an empty array (`[]`). This leads to your other question...:

> I don't understand why this recursion stops and does not go into an
> endless loop

as you traverse your nodes in your tree, you'll eventually reach your *leaf nodes* (nodes with no descendants (`.descendants` is an empty array)). When this occurs, your `.forEach()` loop won't run the code within its "callback", and so no further recursive calls to `show_tree()` are made. Instead, the function returns to its caller, which can begin to "unravel" the recursive calls or continue looping over other sibling nodes.

Comment: Shame on me... Yes, there was a typo... Of course - length. Thank you for an explanation about forEach, now everything is clear.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answers to your questions are:

1. There's a typo in the line `root_node.descendants.lenght != 0`, we can change this to  `root_node.descendants.length != 0`
2. `root_node.descendants` won't be `undefined`, it will be [], or an empty array, so the forEach simply won't run, which is probably the desired behaviour.

I've modified your methods slightly, including a v1 and v2 suffix to differentiate them, and added a *depth* argument, so we can log the node depth. Also, instead of using alert(), we'll just use console.log().

Running each works now I think, the v1 method will log the leaf nodes only, while the v2 method will log all nodes.

```js
class tree_node {
  constructor(n_array) {
    this.n_array = n_array;
    this.descendants = [];
    this.child();
  }
  child() {
    if (this.n_array.length !=1){
      let m = Math.floor(this.n_array.length / 2);
      let l = this.n_array.slice(0,m);
      let r = this.n_array.slice(m);
      const left = new tree_node(l);
      const right = new tree_node(r);
      this.descendants.push(left, right);
    }
    else return 0
  }
}

function show_tree_v1(root_node, depth = 0) {
  if (root_node.descendants.length != 0){
    root_node.descendants.forEach(element => {
      return show_tree_v1(element, depth + 1);
    });
  } else {
    console.log('show_tree_v1: [', root_node.n_array.join(","), '] , depth:', depth)
    return 0;
  } 
}

function show_tree_v2(root_node, depth = 0){
  console.log('show_tree_v2: n_array: [', root_node.n_array.join(","), '], depth:', depth)
  root_node.descendants.forEach(element => {
    return show_tree_v2(element, depth + 1);
  });  
}

let n_array = [1,3,2,5];
root_node = new tree_node(n_array);

console.log('Show tree (v1):')
show_tree_v1(root_node)

console.log('Show tree (v2):')
show_tree_v2(root_node)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Yes, there was a typo... Of course - length, thank you.
And thanks for your two versions of show_tree_v2!

Comment: Glad to help @DonBobskiy, thanks for posting your question!